# Can't Unzip on Windows Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-server-2008-r2, zip

I'm writing a script to extract a zip file on a server running Windows Server 2008 R2. The unzipping works perfect on my mac after testing it but on the server an unzipped folder isn't generated and if I search the machine for the file only the zipped file is present so this says to me that there is no unzipping taking place.

Here is the server side script

```
def extractZip(*pass in file name*):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(fileName, 'r')
    zf.debug =3
    zf.extractall()
    print(zf)
    zf.close()
```

This is 100% identical to the code on my mac that does work. Anything I'm missing here? Is there a difference with Unzipping on Windows

Comment: Set ZipFile.debug to true, and check the output. extractall extracts to current directory, maybe permissions issue?

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? Thanks very much

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html  in your case: zf.debug = True

Comment: I altered the code example above. when I print(zf) I get the file name and mode = 'r'

Comment: Oh yes, sorry debug is not a boolean but level... So you don't have any debug output? Have you tried specifing an output directory?

Comment: well I haven't used the debug before so i am unfamiliar with it. If you look at the solution and assuming I didn't make a mistake with the debug then no I am getting no debug output. I have tried specifying the output directory but still nothing

Comment: Can you open the file with Python? What does `os.path.isfile(path)` give you? Perhaps it's a simple permission issue.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I just tried that and nothing shows.

Comment: Meaning you can open the file without an error?

Comment: What happens when you try to create a file the current working directory, e.g. `f = open(os.getcwd() + '\\tmp.txt') f.close()`? Try changing `extractall` to `extractall(somepath)` where you have read/write access.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Yeah it doesn't create that file. Very strange I can manually unzip them and create folders though. I just contacted the admin and hopefully there is something he can do but it is strange,